# Cannot convert List to IEnumerable when combining 2 generic lists MVC C#

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have 2 lists generated by `LINQ` using `ViewModels` that I would like to combine into one list and show in a datatable on my Home View. I have tested both lists separately, and they each bring back the results I am expecting. I've found a couple ways to combine the lists, but I am not able to combine the lists to send back to my `View`. Can someone help guide me to the answer here?

Using the code below, I have intellisense telling me `list.AddRange(personnelList);` and `list.AddRange(nonPersonnelList);` are wrong. The issue is that it `cannot convert from Generic.List to Generic.IEnumerable`.

Controller:

```
List<PersonnelViewModel> personnelList = (from p in db.Personnel
     where p.ActiveFG == true
     join pd in db.PersonnelDetail on p.ID equals pd.PersonnelID into pdGroup
     from pdItem in pdGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join pos in db.Position on p.PrimaryPositionID equals pos.ID into posGroup
     from posItem in posGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join d in db.Department on posItem.DepartmentID equals d.ID into dGroup
     from dItem in dGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join l in db.Locations on p.PrimaryLocation equals l.ID into lGroup
     from lItem in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join b in db.Building on lItem.BuildingID equals b.ID into bGroup
     from bItem in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join f in db.FaxMachine on pdItem.FaxID equals f.ID into fGroup
     from fItem in fGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new PersonnelViewModel
     {
         ID = p.ID,
         DisplayName = p.DisplayName ?? string.Empty,
         EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress ?? string.Empty,
         PhotoLocation = p.PhotoLocation ?? string.Empty,
         PortNumber = pdItem.PhonePort ?? string.Empty,
         SwitchPort = pdItem.SwitchPort ?? string.Empty,
         PrimaryPositionTitle = posItem.PositionTitle ?? string.Empty,
         Supervisor = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == posItem.SupervisorID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
         PrimaryDepartmentName = dItem.DepartmentName ?? string.Empty,
         DirectoryAssistant = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == dItem.DirectoryAssistantPositionID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
         PrimaryRoomNumber = lItem.RoomNumber ?? string.Empty,
         PrimaryBuildingName = bItem.BuildingName ?? string.Empty,
         FaxNumber = fItem.Number ?? string.Empty,
         BuildingMonitor = (bool)pdItem.BuildingMonitor,
         CPRTrained = (bool)pdItem.CPRTrained,
         CPRTrainedExpirationDate = pdItem.CPRTrainedExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
         DirectDial = (bool)pdItem.DirectDial,
         AEDTrained = (bool)pdItem.DefibrillatorTrained,
         AEDTrainedExpirationDate = pdItem.DefibrillatorTrainedExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
         PrimaryExtension = (int)pdItem.Extension,
         NotaryPublic = (bool)pdItem.NotaryPublic,
         NotaryPublicExpirationDate = pdItem.NotaryPublicExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
         ActiveFG = (bool)p.ActiveFG,
         Person = true,
         LastUpdatedBy = p.LastUpdatedBy,
         LastUpdatedDate = p.LastUpdatedDate.Value,
     }).ToList();

List<NonPersonnelViewModel> nonPersonnelList = (from np in db.NonPersonnel
    where np.ActiveFG == true
    join npt in db.NonPersonnelTypes on np.NonPersonnelTypesID equals npt.ID into nptGroup
    from nptItem in nptGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join dpt in db.Department on np.DepartmentID equals dpt.ID into dptGroup
    from dptItem in dptGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join a in db.Area on dptItem.AreaID equals a.ID into aGroup
    from aItem in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join div in db.Division on aItem.DivisionID equals div.ID into divGroup
    from divItem in divGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join l in db.Locations on np.LocationID equals l.ID into lGroup
    from lItem in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join b in db.Building on lItem.BuildingID equals b.ID into bGroup
    from bItem in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in db.Sites on bItem.SiteID equals s.ID into sGroup
    from sItem in sGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new NonPersonnelViewModel
    {
        ID = np.ID,
        NonPersonnelDescription = nptItem.NonPersonnelDescription ?? string.Empty,
        DepartmentName = dptItem.DepartmentName ?? string.Empty,
        DivisionName = divItem.DivisionName ?? string.Empty,
        AreaName = aItem.AreaName ?? string.Empty,
        Site = string.Concat((sItem.AddressLine1 ?? string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine + (sItem.AddressLine2 ?? string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine +
        (sItem.City ?? string.Empty) + " " + (sItem.State ?? string.Empty) + ", " + (sItem.Zip ?? string.Empty)),
        Switchboard = sItem.Switchboard ?? string.Empty,
        DirectoryAssistant = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == dptItem.DirectoryAssistantPositionID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
        RoomNumber = lItem.RoomNumber ?? string.Empty,
        BuildingName = bItem.BuildingName ?? string.Empty,
        Person = false,
        ActiveFG = (bool)np.ActiveFG,
        LastUpdatedBy = np.LastUpdatedBy,
        LastUpdatedDate = np.LastUpdatedDate.Value,
    }).ToList();

List<HomeViewModel> list = new List<HomeViewModel>();
list.AddRange(personnelList);
list.AddRange(nonPersonnelList);
// combine lists to show in master list on home page
return View(list);
```

ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<PersonnelViewModel> PersonnelList { get; set; }
    public List<NonPersonnelViewModel> NonPersonnelList { get; set; }
}
```

Now the view is where I am calling `@model IEnumerable<Models.HomeViewModel` but this works fine when I just want to display one of the 2 lists. I thought maybe updating

```
public List<PersonnelViewModel> PersonnelList { get; set; }
public List<NonPersonnelViewModel> NonPersonnelList { get; set; }
```

and adding `.AsEnumerable` to both queries would help, but I still have the same error message about not being about to convert from List to IEnumerable.

Adding `.AsEnumerable()` to each of the `.AddRange` for the final list only generates an error saying `cannot convert from Generic.IEnumerable<PersonnelViewModel> to Generic.IEnumerable<HomeViewModel>`

Is this something that is possible to do? I have to get all Personnel and NonPersonnel records to show up on the same page since I am making an online directory, so this has to be accomplished one way or another. I just hope I am on the right track and don't need to rework a lot of this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE with working code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<IndexViewModel> personnelList = (from p in db.Personnel
                             where p.ActiveFG == true
                             join pd in db.PersonnelDetail on p.ID equals pd.PersonnelID into pdGroup
                             from pdItem in pdGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join pos in db.Position on p.PrimaryPositionID equals pos.ID into posGroup
                             from posItem in posGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join d in db.Department on posItem.DepartmentID equals d.ID into dGroup
                             from dItem in dGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join l in db.Locations on p.PrimaryLocation equals l.ID into lGroup
                             from lItem in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join b in db.Building on lItem.BuildingID equals b.ID into bGroup
                             from bItem in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join f in db.FaxMachine on pdItem.FaxID equals f.ID into fGroup
                             from fItem in fGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new IndexViewModel
                             {
                                 ID = p.ID,
                                 DisplayName = p.DisplayName ?? string.Empty,
                                 EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress ?? string.Empty,
                                 PhotoLocation = p.PhotoLocation ?? string.Empty,
                                 PortNumber = pdItem.PhonePort ?? string.Empty,
                                 SwitchPort = pdItem.SwitchPort ?? string.Empty,
                                 PositionTitle = posItem.PositionTitle ?? string.Empty,
                                 Supervisor = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == posItem.SupervisorID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
                                 DepartmentName = dItem.DepartmentName ?? string.Empty,
                                 DirectoryAssistant = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == dItem.DirectoryAssistantPositionID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
                                 RoomNumber = lItem.RoomNumber ?? string.Empty,
                                 BuildingName = bItem.BuildingName ?? string.Empty,
                                 FaxNumber = fItem.Number ?? string.Empty,
                                 BuildingMonitor = (bool)pdItem.BuildingMonitor,
                                 CPRTrained = (bool)pdItem.CPRTrained,
                                 CPRTrainedExpirationDate = pdItem.CPRTrainedExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
                                 DirectDial = (bool)pdItem.DirectDial,
                                 AEDTrained = (bool)pdItem.DefibrillatorTrained,
                                 AEDTrainedExpirationDate = pdItem.DefibrillatorTrainedExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
                                 Extension = (int)pdItem.Extension,
                                 NotaryPublic = (bool)pdItem.NotaryPublic,
                                 NotaryPublicExpirationDate = pdItem.NotaryPublicExpirationDate ?? default(DateTime),
                                 ActiveFG = (bool)p.ActiveFG,
                                 Person = true,
                                 LastUpdatedBy = p.LastUpdatedBy,
                                 LastUpdatedDate = p.LastUpdatedDate.Value,
                             }).ToList();

        List<IndexViewModel> nonPersonnelList = (from np in db.NonPersonnel
                                where np.ActiveFG == true
                                join npt in db.NonPersonnelTypes on np.NonPersonnelTypesID equals npt.ID into nptGroup
                                from nptItem in nptGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join dpt in db.Department on np.DepartmentID equals dpt.ID into dptGroup
                                from dptItem in dptGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join a in db.Area on dptItem.AreaID equals a.ID into aGroup
                                from aItem in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join div in db.Division on aItem.DivisionID equals div.ID into divGroup
                                from divItem in divGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join l in db.Locations on np.LocationID equals l.ID into lGroup
                                from lItem in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join b in db.Building on lItem.BuildingID equals b.ID into bGroup
                                from bItem in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join s in db.Sites on bItem.SiteID equals s.ID into sGroup
                                from sItem in sGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                select new IndexViewModel
                                {
                                    ID = np.ID,
                                    DisplayName = nptItem.NonPersonnelDescription ?? string.Empty,
                                    DepartmentName = dptItem.DepartmentName ?? string.Empty,
                                    DivisionName = divItem.DivisionName ?? string.Empty,
                                    AreaName = aItem.AreaName ?? string.Empty,
                                    Site = string.Concat((sItem.AddressLine1 ?? string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine + (sItem.AddressLine2 ?? string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine +
                                    (sItem.City ?? string.Empty) + " " + (sItem.State ?? string.Empty) + ", " + (sItem.Zip ?? string.Empty)),
                                    Switchboard = sItem.Switchboard ?? string.Empty,
                                    DirectoryAssistant = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.ID == dptItem.DirectoryAssistantPositionID).Select(n => n.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
                                    RoomNumber = lItem.RoomNumber ?? string.Empty,
                                    BuildingName = bItem.BuildingName ?? string.Empty,
                                    Person = false,
                                    ActiveFG = (bool)np.ActiveFG,
                                    LastUpdatedBy = np.LastUpdatedBy,
                                    LastUpdatedDate = np.LastUpdatedDate.Value,
                                }).ToList();

        var list = new List<IndexViewModel>(personnelList);            
        list.AddRange(nonPersonnelList);
        // combine lists to show in master list on home page
        return View(list);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    // personnel //

    public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoLocation { get; set; }
    public string PositionTitle { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryPositionTitle { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryDepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryDivisionName { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryAreaName { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryExtension { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryBuildingName { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryRoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryLocation { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public int Voicemail { get; set; }
    public string PortNumber { get; set; }
    public string SwitchPort { get; set; }
    public bool DirectDial { get; set; }
    public bool BuildingMonitor { get; set; }
    public bool NotaryPublic { get; set; }
    public DateTime NotaryPublicExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public bool CPRTrained { get; set; }
    public DateTime CPRTrainedExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public bool AEDTrained { get; set; } // DefibrillatorTrained
    public DateTime AEDTrainedExpirationDate { get; set; } // DefibrillatorTrainedExpirationDate


    // both //

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public int Extension { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Switchboard { get; set; }
    public string DirectoryAssistant { get; set; }
    public string MailboxLocation { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveFG { get; set; }
    public bool Person { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you quite certain that's the full error message? Because it looks like you're trying to add items of one type, to a list that holds a different type of item. Is `PersonnelViewModel` a base class of `NonPersonnelViewModel`, or vice versa? Do they both have a common base class? Can you show us what "updating the HomeViewModel with IList" means in terms of code?

Comment: I changed `public List<PersonnelViewModel> PersonnelList {get;set;}` to `public IList<PersonnelViewModel> PersonnelList {get;set;}` and updated the `LINQ` statement to `select new PersonnelViewModel ...   .ToEnumerable().ToList()`

Comment: I am indeed trying to add items of one type to a list of another type. I assumed that creating the `HomeViewModel` with the 2 list types in it would allow both lists to be combined on one page. If that isn't correct, is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Do these types have anything in common? Why do you think they could be combined into the same list if they are different types?

Comment: Both types use multiple tables to share data, but the main difference is that one is labeled a person and the other is not. So, if some data fields do not have matching data names in the ViewModels, this won't work?

Comment: @Jamie Why not use the same viewmodel class for both? Give it all the properties it needs to be either one, plus an IsPersonel bool flag. Then they’re interchangeable, they can go in the same List, etc.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what a generic `List<>` is - it is a collection of objects _of the same type_. You have an egg carton, it holds eggs. You have a glass of egg whites, and a glass of egg yolks, and you are trying to pour them into the egg carton. That doesn't work.

Comment: Square pegs in square holes, and round pegs in round holes, might be a better analogy than NetMage’s. .NET is pretty strict about what goes in which box.

Comment: If they don't have fields in common, what do you intend to display on the page? You can't even display the `DisplayName` since it would only exist for some of the rows. You need to decide what is going to be shown and define a class that contains only those fields, and use it for both types. Then you could put them in the same list.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was initially hoping that if `Person = true` then I could show `Personnel.DisplayName` else show `NonPersonnel.Description` but if that isn't doable I will find another way. I don't know why they are insistent on having building names and phone numbers listed in the directory along with the staff/faculty/etc, but I am just trying to do what I can with what I was given.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was actually trying to set up a `ViewModel` with all the properties of both last week when I first started this project, then fell into the Google rabbithole and changed my mind. Glad to see I was starting on the right path.

Comment: @Jamie A viewmodel can have display properties like `public String DisplayDescription => IsPerson ? DisplayName : Description;` for cases where you want a given column to show slightly different information for different types of rows. Another point: Once you've got a single `PersonViewModel` it may make sense to store the two lists as separate lists, but add a readonly property to `HomeViewModel` such as `IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> AllPersons => PersonnelList.Concat(NonPersonnelList);` then use `AllPersons` in the view.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate the help and explanations!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to force two lists into a view model for a view that expects a list.  While it seems to be a common practice to use a list as a view model, I find that it's not very maintainable in the long run and that it's better to create a view-specific view model class as a container from the start.  There's always the possibility that you'll have to add something to the view model later and it's easier to adapt if all you have to do is add a property.

The thing is, you're almost there.  You have `HomeViewModel`, which has both lists as properties.  All you need to do (at least, in the action method) is populate the properties and hand that off to the view.

```cs
HomeViewModel viewModel = new HomeViewModel()
{
    PersonnelList = personnelList,
    NonPersonnelList = nonPersonnelList 
};

return View(viewModel);
```

In your view, change the model type and you'll have `Model.PersonnelList` and `Model.NonPersonnelList` available.

```
@model <whatever the namespace is>.HomeViewModel
```

These classes appear to be different enough that they're going to have very different output, plus you're adding them in order--personnel followed by non-personnel--so looping through them separately make sense.

```cs
@foreach (var personnel in Model.PersonnelList)
{
    @* Display 'personnel' data *@
}

@foreach (var nonPersonnel in Model.NonPersonnelList)
{
    @* Display 'nonPersonnel' data *@
}
```

As a side note, on the guess that this is the `Index` action method in `HomeController`, I suggest renaming `HomeViewModel` to `IndexViewModel` and putting it in a `HomeModels` folder under the `Models` folder.  This way of organizating classes will help keep view models and related classes organized.

---

*A Bit of Compromise*

If you really need them in the same list, it's not going to be as straight-forward but it is possible.

Your list has to be declared to hold instances that are assignable to a common type.  `List<object>` would work for what you have now because they have essentially nothing in common.  That's not so good.

You could declare a base class, e.g. `BasePersonViewModel`, and move some common properties to it, such as `ID`, `ActiveFG`, `Person`, `LastUpdatedBy`, and `LastUpdatedDate`.  That would allow you to do something with all of them, such as sorting by `LastUpdatedDate`.  *(It's still not clear if 'non-personnel' is a different type of person or something that's not a person, so the name may not be right--just bear with me.)*

```cs
IEnumerable<BasePersonViewModel> viewModel = personnel.AsEnumerable<BasePerson>()
    .Concat(nonPersonnel)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdatedDate);

return View(viewModel);
```

Whether or not you create a base class of your own, each item in the list will have to be cast to the correct type to use its properties.

```cs
@* Assuming Model is List<BasePersonViewModel> *@
@foreach (BasePersonViewModel item in Model)
{
    @* display common data such as item.ID *@

    @if (item is PersonnelViewModel personnel)
    {
        @* Display 'personnel' data *@
    }
    else if (item is NonPersonnelViewModel nonPersonnel)
    {
        @* Display 'nonPersonnel' data *@
    }
}
```

Having said that, you should go with separate lists if at all possible.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, which was to send the lists back to the view and make sure the declaration is `@model IEnumerable<Models.IndexViewModel>` (I renamed it based on your suggestion) but when I try to use `Model.PersonnelList` or `Model.NonPersonnelList` in the view, intellisense tells me `IEnumerable<IndexViewModel> does not contain a definition for PersonnelList and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type IEnumerable<IndexViewModel> could be found` Do you know why it would say that?

Comment: It should be `@model IndexViewModel` to match the type of the object you passed to the `View(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and suggestions! I ended up combining all the data from the `PersonnelViewModel` and the `NonPersonnelViewModel` into the `IndexViewModel` and finding the similarities, then updated my `HomeController` to combine the `personnelList` and the `nonPersonnelList`, sent back to the view and it all works perfectly. I'll add the solution to an edit on the original post in case it helps someone in the future.